# How to trigger key events in p5.js

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I want my code to press keyboard keys if a certain condition is True in p5js library. For example:

```js
a = true

if (a) {
  // Press UP Key
} else {
  // Press DOWN Key
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to mimic key press?

Comment: I am using PoseNet to play a game using body movements. So when my hand moves to the right I want the RIGHT_ARROW pressed.

Comment: Just extract the logic from key press handlers to have them in separated functions. Then when your "condition" occurs call the function(s).

Comment: using keyPressed() you can add all your logic inside this function. Check out the link below. https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyPressed

Comment: @SamsonIyanda keyPressed() is useful when I press a key on my keyboard. I want the code to manually press the key if a condition is met.

Comment: @klimat from jquery?

Comment: [Kid creates useless robot to press F key](https://www.buzzvideos.com/technology/423576/kid-creates-useless-robot-to-press-f-key)

Answer (score 1):

P5.js is a JavaScript library, so if you can't find a solution in p5.js, you can do a search for something like "JavaScript trigger key press" for a ton of results.

Another option is to set the p5.js variables you reference manually and then call the `keyPressed()` function yourself. Something like this:

```js
let fillVal = 126;

function draw() {
  fill(fillVal);
  rect(25, 25, 50, 50);
}

function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
    fillVal = 255;
  } else if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {
    fillVal = 0;
  }
  return false; // prevent default
}

function mousePressed() {
  keyCode = UP_ARROW;
  keyPressed();
}
```

The best option is probably what klimat suggested in the comments: extract your logic into a function that you call from both the `keyPressed()` function and from wherever you want to simulate a key press.

Comment: I want the right key pressed when a value is set to true and that right key press will change position of my object in a game(Online game not made by me). So the keyPressed() function is useless for me.

Comment: @YashKhasgiwala Then the best thing I can do is recommend a Google search for a pure JavaScript solution. You should probably include that information in your question though.

Comment: I used  - document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { keyCode: 70, ctrlKey: true })); in my if statement to press Cntrl F from code. It did not work.